# Unity List spawner problem ? C#

Tags: unity, c#, software-engineering

I have four spawners in my scene that spawns four enemies. My problem is when I try to add game objects to the list it works but only for one spawner.

My code

```
if (Score.levelNum >=2 ){
  germtype.Remove(pupplegerm);
  germtype.Add(blackgerm);
  germtype.Add(blackgerm);
}
else if(Score.levelNum >=3 ){
  germtype.Remove(bluegerm);
  germtype.Add(greengerm);
  germtype.Add(greengerm);
}
```

I want to add a new enemy / germ each time the player moves up a level. I have green germ and black germ stored in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `else` from the other conditions, as only the first condition triggers. That is because something greater than or equal to three is also greater than two.